# Most Frequent Pair - Python

Tags: python, group-by

I am trying to find the most frequent combination of product names in a column for each transaction number. I have tried using groupby and dummy variables but can't seem to get too far with them. Here is a sample from the original dataframe:

```
         Timestamp  Transaction Number  Product UPC Number  Price    Retailer  
\
0  3/2/18 08:15:50              123098        111100001234   1.80   Fast Mart   
1  3/2/18 08:15:50              123098        111100001235  23.45   Fast Mart   
2  3/2/18 08:15:50              123098        111100001236   6.99   Fast Mart   
3  3/2/18 08:19:52              123099        111100001236   6.99  Quick Stop   
4  3/2/18 08:19:52              123099        111100001237   7.15  Quick Stop   

          Product Name  
0           Coke 20 oz  
1  Miller Lite 24 Pack  
2        Pepsi 12 Pack  
3        Pepsi 12 Pack  
4         Coke 12 Pack
```

Right now all my code has led to dead ends. The question is: how can I find the most frequent pair of 'Product Name' values across each unique 'Transaction Number'?

Code:

```
dummy_df = pd.get_dummies(pos_df,columns = ['Product Name'])
dummy_df.groupby('Transaction Number').sum().head()
```

This leads me to a spot with data that I am not sure how to use. Would appreciate any insights.

Comment: Please provide dome runnable code you tried and state your question.

Comment: Right now all my code has led to dead ends. The question is: how can I find the most frequent pair of 'Product Name' values across each unique 'Transaction Number'?

Comment: Fair enought. I put what I got to.

Comment: There are similar questions. This particular one seems to cover your exact scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495507/finding-the-most-frequent-occurrences-of-pairs-in-a-list-of-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by pandas dataframe and select most common string factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222754/group-by-pandas-dataframe-and-select-most-common-string-factor)