# Python: Finding the most frequent occurrences of combinations of any length in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to find most occurring combinations in a list of lists. Combinations length can be any.

So, sample data:

```
l = [['action','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['drama','romance'],
 ['comedy','drama','romance'],
 ['scifi','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['horror','mystery','thriller']]
```

Expected output:

```
'mystery','horror','thriller' - 3 times
'drama','romance' - 2 times
```

With the help of [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495507/finding-the-most-frequent-occurrences-of-pairs-in-a-list-of-lists), I was able to find out most occurring pairs(combination of 2), but how to extend it find combinations of any length.

**EDIT:** As per @CrazyChucky's comment:

Sample input:

```
l = [['action','mystery','horror','thriller'],
     ['drama','romance'],
     ['comedy','drama','romance'],
     ['scifi','mystery','horror','thriller'],
     ['horror','mystery','thriller'],
     ['mystery','horror']]
```

Expected output:

```
'mystery','horror' - 4 times
'mystery','horror','thriller' - 3 times
'drama','romance' - 2 times
```

Comment: Is the order matters? Are the lists sorted?

Comment: @adirabargil No, lists are not sorted. Order does not matter at all.

Comment: How do you want to handle comparisons between combinations... For instance, say you added one more entry: `['mystery', 'horror']`. Should the output contain both `3` for `'mystery', 'horror', 'thriller'` *and* `4` for `'mystery', 'horror'`? Or should it pick one or the other? Would frequency or length take precedence?

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes exactly. In that case, output should be `'mystery','horror'- 4 times` and `'mystery','horror','thriller' - 3 times`.

Comment: Given your reply to CrazyChucky's you should amend the question

Comment: @Pynchia Have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the code from that question to iterate over all the possible combinations of each possible size from each sublist:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

l = [['action','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['drama','romance'],
 ['comedy','drama','romance'],
 ['scifi','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['horror','mystery','thriller']]
d  = Counter()
for sub in l:
    if len(sub) < 2:
        continue
    sub.sort()
    for sz in range(2, len(sub)+1):
        for comb in combinations(sub, sz):
            d[comb] += 1

print(d.most_common())
```

Output:

```
[
 (('horror', 'mystery'), 3),
 (('horror', 'thriller'), 3),
 (('mystery', 'thriller'), 3),
 (('horror', 'mystery', 'thriller'), 3),
 (('drama', 'romance'), 2),
 (('action', 'horror'), 1),
 (('action', 'mystery'), 1),
 (('action', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('action', 'horror', 'mystery'), 1),
 (('action', 'horror', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('action', 'mystery', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('action', 'horror', 'mystery', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('comedy', 'drama'), 1),
 (('comedy', 'romance'), 1),
 (('comedy', 'drama', 'romance'), 1),
 (('horror', 'scifi'), 1),
 (('mystery', 'scifi'), 1),
 (('scifi', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('horror', 'mystery', 'scifi'), 1),
 (('horror', 'scifi', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('mystery', 'scifi', 'thriller'), 1),
 (('horror', 'mystery', 'scifi', 'thriller'), 1)
]
```

To get just the genres which have the highest count you can iterate over the counter:

```
most_frequent = [g for g, cnt in d.items() if cnt == d.most_common(1)[0][1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Your answer gives me all the combinations. In this case, I'll have to loop it one more time to find out the combinations with max number, right?

Comment: Neat solution. Have you seen CrazyChucky's comment above? (and OP's reply)

Comment: @MayankPorwal you can get the genres with the maximum occurrence using `most_frequent = [g for g, cnt in d.items() if cnt == d.most_common(1)[0][1]]`

Comment: @Pynchia been away, just saw the comments, I think my comment above resolves that for OP

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code without importing any packages

```py
lst = [['action','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['drama','romance'],
 ['comedy','drama','romance'],
 ['scifi','mystery','horror','thriller'],
 ['horror','mystery','thriller']]


def print_it_all_by_num(arr: list):
    dic = dict()
    for i in arr:
        for j in i:
            if j in dic:
                dic[j] += 1
            else:
                dic[j] = 1
    dic_out = dict()
    for i in dic:
        if dic[i] in dic_out:
            dic_out[dic[i]].append(i)
        else:
            dic_out[dic[i]] = [i]
    print(dic_out)  # out is {1: ['action', 'comedy', 'scifi'], 3: ['mystery', 'horror', 'thriller'], 2: ['drama', 'romance']}


print_it_all_by_num(lst)
```

Comment: Why use indexes in python? What is the value of not using modules from the standard library? Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: This code not cover the issue correctly... though it work for the specific case, it counts items that not necessary in the same sublist...